# User accounts missing on loginscreen after 11.10->12.04 upgrade, how to get them back?

Tags: lightdm, users

I upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10. I thought that by upgrading I wouldn't lose the accounts (and the release notes make no reference to loosing it), yes, I carelessly hit the upgrade button but please tell me if all pictures, videos and songs are gone for good?

In the end, isn't that the reason to go for an upgrade instead of a clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you loose media files only? If you changed the language, desktop may search by default in the wrong directories cause of translation, like "Music" in place of "Musique" (in french). Say, media directories defaut name are localized (at least french/english)

Comment: short answer: you are right! ... i had some user accounts in a different language, so when i installed the upgrade i chose that as the installation language, i have backed up those files now!